# Trying to have the option to hide the details column on the page

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out a way to be able to hide the column `<td><?php echo $row['DETAILS']; ?></td>` on the php page by either using a button or by clicking the column. The details is not always needed so I didn't want to completely hide it if not needed. But I have tried a couple options and was not able to get it to work. The data that is being called is from a sql data base. Here is also a screen shot of the front end.

[image: Front End]

```
<tr>
<?php
                              
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?> 
  <td><?php echo $row['VPN']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['START TIME']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['END_TIME']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['RANK']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['PROVIDER']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['CIRCUIT']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['OUTAGE']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['DETAILS']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

I tried adding a button into the `<td>` to make it collapsible, I tried using a class in the `<tr>` as well. I tried couple js options but no luck. IDK what is going on with the indenting but I will say it is not like that or else it would not work lol.

Comment: Where do you close your `while` loop? The `}` is missing from your sample code. It looks like you are starting the table row outside the loop (so you'll only get one row started) but then ending it inside the loop, which clearly makes no sense. At a guess, is it supposed to be one HTML table row per SQL row?

Comment: `But I have tried a couple options`...please show what you tried and explain the issue. This ought to be some fairly straightforward JS. It might help if you gave all the relevant table cells the same CSS class or something, so you can easily target them with a selector in JS, and hide them all at once, or similar. There are lots of previous questions about hiding a table column in JS on this site, and elsewhere, including the one I've marked in the duplicate above. If you had some issues it could possibly be a result of the apparently malformed table layout I've higlighted in my first comment